# Apply base to rusted table and paint?

Tags: corrosion, cast-iron

I have this iron table that seems really rusted, but that’s just a thin layer or rust.  The table’s still extremely solid.

I’d like to apply a base that will stop (or control) the rust and then paint it and give it some color.

What do you recommend? I tried sanding it a few years ago, but it was just next to impossible.

Here’s the *patient*:
[image]

Comment: Remove the rust, either chemically or abrasively. No coating would adhere to rust that flakes off.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way is to sandblast it and immediately prime coat then top coat. A not very good alternative is to power wire brush (such as a drill) then apply "conversion" coating. There are various brands with various claims but it must say phosphate or phosphoric acid , and it is good if it lists manganese; Navel Jelly is a generic. Then follow directions and put on a top coat (for steel, such as farm equipment paint). Depending on exposure this can last for years.